# Is it possible to use a variable to highlight a row in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to highlight rows in a table using jQuery, but I'm wondering if it's possible to use a variable for the row I want highlighted. This is the code I have now, which is not working.

```
  var rowNumber = 3 //I want to use a loop, but for testing purposes I have it set to 3
  $('tr:eq(rowNumber)').addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: `//I want to use a loop, but for testing purposes I have it set to 3` If you use a loop, then **do not** concatenate the index into a selector inside the loop like that. The DOM selection should be done once, and you should loop over the result. ...this feels like a classic [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).

Comment: I understand that you wanted to solve a very particular problem involving a part of your task.  The above comment, however, is true.  Would you like to give us a bit more detail about your loop and what it is meant to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, why not. You may pass a variable in [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$("tr:eq(" + rowNumber + ")").addClass("highlight");
```

or use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method instead:

```
$("tr").eq(rowNumber).addClass("highlight");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('tr').eq(rowNumber).addClass('highlight');
```

Should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first address isolated access (i.e. not taking into consideration optimisation for loops)

- Best solution:  Use .eq()  (fast, nice and short)

You could try something like

```
$('tr').eq(rowNumber).addClass('highlight');
```

Explanation: .eq(index) Reduces the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

- Alternative solution: Use the ":eq(index)" selector (unnecessarily slower, more verbose and convoluted)

  $("tr:eq("+rowNumber+")").addClass('highlight');
- A third solution: (fast, but more verbose than the proposed solution)
  $($('tr').get(rowNumber)).addClass('highlight');

How this one works: $('tr').get(rowNumber) gets the (rowNumber+1)th DOM element matching the query selector and then this is wrapped in jQuery goodness using the surrounding $( ).

More info at: http://api.jquery.com/get/

Feel free to experiment with the accompanying jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FuLJE/

---

If you are particularly performance conscious and are indeed are going to iterate through an array you can do this instead:

```
var trs = $('tr').get();  //get without arguments return the entire array of matched DOM elements
var rowNumber, len = trs.length; 
for(rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < len; rowNumber++) {
   var $tr = $(trs[rowNumber]);
   //various stuff here
   $tr.addClass('highlight');
   //more stuff here
}
```

Of course you could also use .each()

```
$("tr").each(function (rowNumber, tr) {
   var $tr = $(tr);
   //various stuff here
   $tr.addClass('highlight');
   //more stuff here
})
```

Documentation can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Just to point out the obvious: $("tr").addClass('highlight') would work if adding the highlight class to all tr was all that the OP wanted to do :-)